# NFC (or alternative) device to send data from phone to server

Tags: nfc

What i want to do is get some kind of nfc reader so i can put my smartphone on top of it and it sends some data to my server. For example i have app where i store my name and when i put my phone on top of the device it sends "John says hi" to my server.

I am not sure which keywords i should use to find this kind of device but i think that there should be devices like that because there is mobile pay etc.

And if there is not any devices like that is there any alternatives for example device that works with bluetooth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply buy a cheap NFC-Tag and program it, so that it opens an URL on your Server or start an App which sends something to your server.
They are very cheap and easily programmable.

Comment: Oh that sounds great. Thank you!